# Square Point of Sales API sending reference_id or userInfoString

Tags: ios, square, square-connect

I'm using point of sales API to integrate a webapp with Square point of sales for IOS.
according to the API, if I send a reference in my transaction request I'll get that reference back in the response URL and that's what I want to use that reference for further processing in my app.However I'm not getting the reference in the response so I guess something is wrong in my request
this is my request object

```
 var dataParameter = {
            amount_money: {
                amount:amount * 100,
                currency_code: "USD"
            },


            callback_url: myURL,

            reference_id: referenceId,

            client_id: applicationId,

            version: "1.3",
            notes: "this is a test",

            options: {
                supported_tender_types: ["CREDIT_CARD", "CASH"],
                auto_return: true

            }

        }
```

I also tried  "userInfoString" instead of "reference_id" and it didn't work.

Comment: I used the retrieve transaction request by the transactionId and the response has referenceId = null

Comment: Are you talking about the iOS POS Web API? The request doesn't have a `reference_id`, so I'm not sure what you're referring to. There is a `state` field that will be returned on in the response URL, maybe that's what you're looking for? https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/pos/web-technical-reference#ios-data-fields

Comment: Yes I apologize I realized that the request doesn’t have a reference id . The state is what I need thank you so much